# Lucky Draw (Random Number Generation)

Tags: random, numbers, generator

I need a software or a program environment for lucky draw with below capabilities:

- Completely random selection method
- Without using definite seed and increment (non predictable fashion)
- Not dependent to first selection
- Random numbers can be generated based on environmental factors such as time, temperature, internet traffic, atmospheric noise but not from simple random mathematical functions.

Can you help me about this?

thanks

Comment: What have you tried? There's lots of info on PRNGs here and on the wider internet.

Comment: Maybe looking for an hardware RNG?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hardware_random_number_generators

Comment: So you're saying you want a random number generator that doesn't use a seed, but is seeded with factors such as time?

Comment: How often do you need to generate numbers? Is once a day good enough?

Comment: You may find that a cryptographic RNG meets your criteria better than a usual RNG.  Have a look at whatever your language supplies for crypto use, or else implement Yarrow, Fortuna or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to computationally generate random numbers, and it is known as the Multiply with Carry Method by George Marsaglia. The advantages of this method is that is it not increment based nor is it seeded in a pattern. Rather it has a random seed.

P.S This application is not Thread Safe

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-with-carry

Code is from this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Computational_methods

```
m_w = <choose-initializer>;    /* must not be zero */
m_z = <choose-initializer>;    /* must not be zero */

uint get_random()
{
    m_z = 36969 * (m_z & 65535) + (m_z >> 16);
    m_w = 18000 * (m_w & 65535) + (m_w >> 16);
    return (m_z << 16) + m_w;  /* 32-bit result */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If by "lucky draw" you mean that you need a number only once a day, or so, you can use the low digits, including the fractional digits, of a publicly accessible stock market index, such as NASDAQ or S&P 500. You can also use several of these indices and mix the digits using a hash function to get a single larger number.